# spark-submit --status with mesos master returns nothing

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I'd like to retrieve the status of a spark job running in cluster mode on a mesos master via the following:

```
spark-submit --master mesos://<ip>:7077 --status "driver-...-..."
```

It exits `0` with no logging, no matter what the driver's status is.

I know that it's doing something right, since if I run the command with a an invalid mesos ip/port, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: Unable to connect to server
at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:165)
```

and if I run with an invalid submission id, I get

```
2018-10-02 18:47:01 ERROR RestSubmissionClient:70 - Error: Server responded with message of unexpected type SubmissionStatusResponse.
```

Any idea why `spark-submit --status` isn't returning anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by accessing the dispatcher's api directly:

`curl -s "http://$DISPATCHER/v1/submissions/status/$SUBMISSION_ID"`

Still no clear answer why `spark-submit --status` does not behave as documented though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of spark you are using. My investigation is based on spark-2.4.0. The described behaviour is valid for both *spark standalone* and *mesos* deployment targets.

`org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient` is used as the handler for rest submission requests and programmatically uses **INFO** level to log the response.

`org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit` is used as a main class when invoking *spark-submit* and its logger is the top level root logger for all other loggers.

Programatically, if specific logger for *SparkSubmit* is not set in *conf/log4j.properties (the same holds when this file is absent)* the default level is set to **WARN**.

Going further, in the absence of the specific logger for *RestSubmissionClient* it gets its root logger's level which is *SparkSubmit*'s logger.

You can see errors because again WARN is default.

To be able to see the logs for rest submissions you may want to adjust ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/log4j.properties with either
`log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient=INFO`
or `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.rest=INFO` for other classes in that package.

Answer (score 0):

Add following
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient=INFO and log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.rest=INFO

to log4j.properties
present under /etc/spark/conf location and again look for status

spark-submit  --master spark://:6066  --status  driver-20210516043704-0012